# animate view in xcode playground not completing

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I am trying to make a custom activity view that spins and flips a logo. I am at the very early stages and building it in xcodes playground. I just want the logo to flip vertically, then horizontally, then vertically again and horizontally again so that the logo is how it began initially. The issue im having is that it is only performing the first flip and then nothing else but i cant see why?

This is what my code in the playground looks like at the moment:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import QuartzCore

class LogoActivityView: UIView {

var animationLoopCount: Int = 0
var logoImageView = UIImageView()
var logoImage = UIImage()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupView()
    setLogoImageView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupView() {

    self.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.isHidden = true
}

func startAnimating() {

    self.isHidden = false

    animationLoopCount
    while animationLoopCount < 2 {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {() -> Void in

            self.logoImageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(.pi, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)

        }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

                self.logoImageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(.pi, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
            }, completion: nil)
        })

        animationLoopCount += 1
    }
}

func setLogoImageView() {

    logoImageView = UIImageView(frame: self.frame)
    logoImage = UIImage(named: "MemoryBoothLogo.png")!

    logoImageView.image = logoImage
    logoImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    logoImageView.backgroundColor = .clear

    self.addSubview(logoImageView)
}
}

let containerView = LogoActivityView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

containerView.startAnimating()
```

Any help would be great thanks

Comment: First of all, you cannot animate "in a loop" like you are trying to do. The loop does not magically wait while the animation takes place; it just does all its loops immediately, kaboom, long before the first animation even gets started. So step one is to "unroll" your loop; do everything as a chain of animation - completion - next animation. Do you see? (You can can write this more cleanly as a keyframe animation, but I'm assuming you don't know how to do that.)

Comment: Second, let's talk about your transforms. They do not do what you think they do. You are setting the view's transform _absolutely_. This means that one transform does not act upon another; rather, you competely _replace_ one transform with another. Thus, you will not rotate back to where you started.

Comment: Third, I have to say, going this in a playground is a pretty bad idea. I would strongly urge you to develop this code in actual iOS app project.

Comment: That explains a lot thanks. Why not in playground?

Comment: Only because it just isn't a very "real" environment. You don't learn how your code _really_ behaves by experimenting in a playground.